# Where condition on populated model does not work in waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using waterline in sails.js and trying to find all records of "User" model which their related "Car" model's id is in a specified list, as follows:

```
var list = [3, 4, 5];
User.find().populate('car', {
    where: {
      id: list
    }
  }).exec(function(err, foundUsers){
    console.log(foundUsers);
  });
```

The problem is that query is executed regardless of list value and all records are returned. How should this criterion be applied?

Models are defined as follows:

```
//User:
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysqlConnection',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    car: {
      model: 'Car'
    }
  }
}
//Car:
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysqlConnection',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never understood why Waterline behaved like this...

But here is a simple way to make it:

```
var list = [3, 4, 5];
User
  .find({ car: list })
  .populate('car')
  .exec(function(err, foundUsers){
    console.log(foundUsers);
  });
```

**EDIT:** as of 2017/01/31, the additional populate doesn't seem to be mandatory anymore. Didn't check the version where it changed though

Comment: That's kind of strange, and not as what is explained in the documents! But it works, thank you.